# Could not load type xxx from assembly xxx

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I'm making a windows application where user selects a type from combo box. Based on the selection, using reflection I want to create instance of the respective type and invoke one of its method.
The Types I want to create are also defined in the same windows app as sperate classes. But i'm getting the error as mentioned in Title. Heres my code.

Form1 code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        cbLogs.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }

    private void btnProcess_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblMessage.Text = "";
        lblResult.Text = "";
        if (cbLogs.SelectedIndex <= 0)
        {
            lblMessage.Text = "Please select Log to be processed";
            cbLogs.Focus();
            return;
        }
        Assembly currAss = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        //I get above error on below line.
        object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(currAss.FullName,"SustainabilityXpress ");
        Type type = obj.GetType();
        object result = type.InvokeMember("process", 
            BindingFlags.Default | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
            null, obj, null);

        lblResult.Text = result.ToString();

    }

}
```

ILogBase Interface:

```
interface ILogBase
{        
    string process();

}
```

SustainabilityXpress class that implements ILogBase:

```
public class SustainabilityXpress: ILogBase
{
    string LogName = "SUSTAINABILITYXPRESS";
    public string process()
    {
        return "Sustainabilityxpress";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Be sure to properly name the `SustainabilityXpress` class -- aren't you forgeting to prepend its namespace? (for instance, "Name.Space.SustainabilityXpress").

Also, check [Activator.CreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d133hta4.aspx) to ensure all requirements are met.

And, as @Grzenio pointed out, there may be a typo in the name `SustainabilityXpress`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is only in the post, but there mustn't be a space in `"SustainabilityXpress "`. You also have to use the full class name (including the namespace).

If this doesn't help, maybe the type simply isn't in the assembly? `GetExecutingAssembly` gets you the assembly where the current code is in ...

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed there is a space in "SustainabilityXpress ". Try deleting it, maybe this was the issue.